# PostgreSQL Query Fields with Specific String Format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database, inside one of the tables is a string field that is formatted something like the following examples...

```
Fall 2017 MAT1277 OO4
```

Yet other fields may be something like this...

```
Fall 2017 Example Course For Name
```

I need to perform a query that ONLY searches for courses that are formatted like the first example (Fall 2017 MAT1277 OO4) but here's the catch. The following will remain the same yet the others will be different for each course.

Fall 2017 XXXXXXX OOX - Where X indicates the characters that will be different. Anyway to perform a query that will only return the course name's that are formatted in this fashion?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Postgres documentation on pattern matching:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you, sir! I just wasn't searching using the right word.